# How to validate whole json with respective schema for integration in java

Tags: java

I am getting as json string and jsonschema string
Please give me as whole json validation at a time with json schema
Both schema and json are strings

Comment: Eh. No. Look at how [`yaml-json-validator-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/sylvainlaurent/yaml-json-validator-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/sylvainlaurent/maven/yamljsonvalidator/ValidationService.java) does it.

Comment: I can't able to download can you suggest other one with Java code